# Why are several resistors used in series instead of one large resistor?

Tags: circuit-design, components

I am studying switch-mode power supplies. For some designs I have seen, the schematic calls for two or more resistors in series instead of one large one.

An example would be the DC1817B evaluation board ([Page 7](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/DC1817BFA.PDF)). A more dramatic example is the [STEVAL-IPB001V1](https://www.digikey.com/reference-designs/en/ac-dc-and-dc-dc-conversion/ac-dc-smps-single-output/468) (schematic below.)

In my case, it's trivial to order 2MOhm 1/8W resistors, or two 30kOhm (there's 60k but it's expensive) off of Digikey for example.

Other than availability and cost, is there any reason for the design choice below?

[image]

Comment: If you are ordering 2M ohm, shouldn't you order 1/4W? Likewise, 60k resistor should be 1.5W. Splitting I see allows using low wattage resistors.

Comment: @sai I didn't think of that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Your schematic doesn't come from the LT paper you linked. Please add a link to the source.

Comment: (AN 2454 page 5/24)

Comment: Metal film resistors have issues with electromigration. High value resistors with high voltage across them are susceptible to this, so having a number of resistors in series mitigates the issue as each resistor sees less voltage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check the datasheet for the resistors you're buying. You will find a voltage limit corresponding with size, separate from the power rating.  And current ratings for smaller values.  All three ratings must be respected.

You may want one or more extra resistors in series to meet a safety standard (protection against single-point-of-failure (SPOF) condition) as well.

The resistors also need to be large enough for the creepage and clearance your board will have (compact HV resistors are available, which only achieve those ratings when immersed in oil, or potted).

Series and parallel combinations may also be used to reach useful values without adding another resistor type to the bill of materials (BOM), saving assembly costs.  This might explain R20 || R21.

Comment: For me, final answer was voltage rating. My design calls for a resistor in parallel with a 630V 1nF capacitor. The SMD resistors I can find are only rated up to 200V. I used 4 in series.

Answer (score 9):

There are 4 reasons I can think of:

1. Share total dissipated power across multiple smaller, cheaper resistors.
2. Achieve a total resistance not readily available in E12 or E24. For example 9.9k = 3.3k × 3
3. Distribute a large potential difference across many cheaper low-voltage resistors instead of a single more expensive one.
4. Reduce the risk of arcing by distributing small chunks of a large potential difference over a much greater total physical distance.

Comment: The point 2) is a bit weird. As E12 has typically 10% tolerance, and E24 has typically 5% tolerance, you would only nominally end up with 9.9K resistance with a 10% or 5% tolerance, so if you really require or can live with 9.9k 5% tolerance, you might as well just get a 10k 2% resistor.

Comment: @Justme Values typically follow a truncated normal distribution, with a 2-3 σ cutoff.  It can always be worse of course, but this seems to be the most common case even among cheap supplies of resistors.  The result is a regression to the mean, i.e. the series combination looks more normally distributed.  Which is to say, the expected error drops, but the min/max is not affected.

Comment: Not in this case, but there is a other possibility some PCBs may have this: To reduce the different articles. You may already use 10 kΩ resistors somewhere and using 2 of them can be cheaper than adding a different one of 20 kΩ

Answer (score 7):

If power dissipated is higher in the resistors, splitting it helps because you can use smaller resistors with low wattage.

Answer (score 4):

One reason would be to limit the voltage across any one resistor. Resistors have a voltage rating, for an 1/8 W surface mount type it might be 300 V. So for high voltages you can use several series resistors to distribute the voltage.

Answer (score 4):

There is a purpose to having multiple resistors.

And also note that even if there is six 10k resistors, it does not mean that they are there because exactly 60k resistance is needed. They are 10k because having six of them with some tolerance is within a suitable range. As you noticed, 60k resistors are not standard and literally don't exist. But if a single resistor could be used, a range of suitable values exist, so 62k might be within specs, or if not, 59.7k then could be. But the resistors with tighter tolerance will be more expensive, so since a range of resistances is fine, the resistor tolerances can also be chosen to be loose enough to have multiple cheap standard resistors.

First reason is obvious, the resistors have a power limit. Having multiple cheap standard resistors that individually heat up less is better than having a single expensive resistor that must handle the power and temperature, and may require more special arrangements to keep it cool, as the multiple  resistors can be distributed evenly and allow the PCB to conduct and redistribute the heat.

The second reason is that resistors have a voltage limit within which they can be safely operated. You can't put multiple hundred volts over a cheap standard resistor, and again, a single special resistor that can handle it will be more expensive. A standard small resistor could typically handle about 200V, and adding up more resistors that together can handle enough overvoltage for reliability is cheap.

Answer (score 3):

Resistors have voltage limits as well as power limits, and these can be surprisingly low in smt parts.

If you are designing mains connected stuff and need to get it past say UL listing, then you need to ensure that a single failure will not produce a dangerous condition for any single component failing. You often see series resistor pairs even where the voltage or power limits are not factors for this reason.

When doing design for a commercial product, attempting to minimise the number of different parts on the BOM is desirable as it makes production faster and thus cheaper. 10k 1/8th W SMT is very likely a part that is just kept permanently on the pick and place machine in a massive real of about 20,000 parts, so they cost nearly nothing.

A 1.5W resistor is firstly likely not SMT and secondly a weird special, that is going to cost you both for the part and because now you are having to do a wave soldering operation as well as reflow. Far better to simply slap down 6 of the 10k parts you have available for no cost rather then adding an extra manufacturing step.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple series resistors also can make failure of a resistor less catastrophic for higher voltage applications if it fails short. For example, in the voltage divider in a differential probe, it is pretty important that if a single resistor in the probe fails that the input voltage is still reduced enough that it can't blast it's way through all the components to the output side. It could even allow repair just be replacing the blown resistor if he divider was designed such that the voltage was kept low enough to not damage other components, even with the shorted resistor. Works for resistor limited diode rail clamps too.

Comment: It's important to note that if a resistor fails shorted because of overvoltage, that would be likely to result in a cascading failure, but (1) it's possible for resistors to fail shorted for other reasons such as physical stress, surface contamination, or manufacturing defects, and (2) even when resistors fail shorted, their resistance doesn't usually drop to zero, and they often absorb some energy when they fail.  Even if failing resistors offer orders of magnitude less protection than working ones, they may reduce the amount of energy reaching downstream components enough to reduce damage.

Answer (score 1):

Possible factors include:

- Voltage isolation
- Heat dissipation
- Price.

Comment: Your answer is correct , but it usually helps to make it longer than a short sentence. Fwiw, the automatic checking system flagged it as low quality for this reason, and others are liable to. It may seem wrong to "pad" things for such reasons, but people tend to be somewhat more comfortable with somewhat more. But, a reasonable answer.

Comment: I edited it while adding nothing. Whether that makes it better is uncertain :-) . || Voltage isolation is more liable to be voltage rating of each resistor - but similar aspects.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me. Thanks :)

Comment: For information only: Very short answers (like the one you made about a power supply) may be converted to comments as as that was (not by me). Adding a little more information keeps the answers visible rather than being buried in comments and may be more useful to others later on.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason I have not seen answered yet is part count:

If your design needs a 60k resistor somewhere, while you already used a 10k resistor somewhere else in the design, you could choose six 10k resistors instead.

Although this increases your part count, it does reduce the amount of different types of parts you're using. This in turn can simplify BOM/supply chain.

Comment: That would be costly

Comment: If it's either three 10k ohms, or one 10k and one 20k, it's definitely worth considering. In other situations it may still be worth considering, depending on the resistor values and their availability. - Maintaining a supply chain is not easy, and simplifying it should be considered.

Comment: Depends on the volume, in 10k or lower this night not be a big deal, in 100k production it would

Comment: This is a valid tactic for SMD boards, but power electronics are often through-hole and wave soldered. What you gain from a shorter BoM, you lose in assembly costs.

Answer (score 0):

1MEG resistors:

The purpose of these resistors is to discharge the input caps when power is removed, in order to make the board (and any wires attached to J1) safe to handle.

Power is very low, 1/8W resistors are used. They are wired in series in order not to exceed the maximum voltage rating of the resistors. SMDs are tiny, distance between pads is also tiny, so the maximum voltage rating is low due to creepage.

6x 10K 1/4W resistors:

All the other resistors are 1/8W and these are 1/4W, which gives a hint that this is about dissipated power. Maximum voltage rating also applies. The purpose of these resistors is to drop voltage and reduce power dissipation in Q3 which provides supply current to the PWM chip in order to start it when the output voltage isn't present yet. So it's a linear regulator from a very high voltage, which means it will have ridiculously low efficiency. At 1200V input voltage, 1mA through Q3 would dissipate almost 1.2 Watts total, so the resistors are necessary.

In this case the number of resistors is probably determined by their voltage rating. But sometimes, using several resistors instead of one with higher power rating can be beneficial:

- If you already have 10kOhm 1/4W in your BOM, and you need 5kOhm 1/2W it can be cheaper to use 2 resistors in parallel instead of one.
- Several resistors helps spread the heat around the board, avoids hotspots, may have better thermal transfer to copper depending on layout
- Sometimes (especially with SMDs) several low power resistors can be cheaper than one high power resistor.